# CSS issue with hover state width in submenu

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

For some reason, my `:hover` state in my submenu only stretches to cover the words but doesn't stretch the width of the submenu box.

Here is the code in [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/kjetterman/NfjXY/58/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following rules to your CSS:

`overflow:hidden` to `li:hover ul.sub`

`display:block` to `ul.sub li a`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NfjXY/62/)**

Comment: You are a rockstar!!  Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: No problem. I just updated my jsFiddle link since it seems the first one was just the same link as yours. BTW, if you feel that this answered your question, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer, upvote it, and tell all your friends about it ;)